# Creating a new column in text file

Tags: scripting

Let's say I have a text file with the following:

```
1
3
5
7
9
```

and I want to paste the following to the right of it while still maintaining the spacing:

```
23 34 53 
22 17 99
```

(Of course I'm using many more numbers, so I can't just do this manually). 
So I want something like this:

```
1 23 34 53
3 22 17 99
5
7
9
```

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `paste` command to merge columns from files as in:

f1:

```
1
3
5
7
9
```

f2:

```
23 34 53
22 17 99
```

Then the command `paste f1 f2` will produce:

```
1 23 34 53
3 22 17 99
5
7
9
```

With a tab character between the portions pasted from each file unless you change the delimiter with the `-d` option.